# Inconsitent results with same logic inside and outside a function

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am writing code to check how many times the string "TIME_DATA" shows up in my log file. I am new to Python so I wrote out the logic then put the logic inside a function to modularize it for my final task.

However when I uncomment the logic outisde of the function I get inconsistent results between the two. So the code is suppose to print out "time data complete" if the count is greater than 7. With the same logic in the two seperate scopes, the top logic returns "time data complete" but this same logic when called after returns "imcomplete time data". Why is this?:

```
tfile = open ('timetest.log', 'r')
tflines1 = tfile.readlines()

time_data_count = 0
for line in tflines1:
    if 'TIME_DATA' in line :
        time_data_count += 1
if time_data_count > 7 :
    print("time_data complete")
else:
    print("incomplete time_data data")

def file_check (f):
    tflines = f.readlines()
    time_data_count = 0
    for line in tflines:
        if 'TIME_DATA' in line:
            time_data_count += 1
    if time_data_count > 7:
        return "time_data complete"
    else:
        return "incomplete time_data data"

print(file_check(tfile))
```

Why does it pass for the top but not for the bottom in the file_check function

**If I comment out the top part, the logic outside the function, the file_check function behaves as it should and returns "time_data complete"**

Comment: Read up on [Tutorial - 9.2. Python Scopes and Namespaces](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#python-scopes-and-namespaces)

Comment: Can you post the error traceback you get? Also, what happens if you close the file right before you define the function and re open it inside the function?

Comment: @MasonCaiby What is an error traceback? Pycharm doesn't give me any errors. It runs the code but shows different results between the two. I didn't attempt to close the read file after I was done withe first  part before opening it up again in the function.I guess I could try it and see if that's the issue

Answer (score 0):

Using `tfile.readlines()` moves the file pointer to the end of the file, so when you try to read it again it returns an empty list. Try adding `f.seek(0)` to your function like so:

```py
def file_check(f):
    f.seek(0)
    tflines = f.readlines()
    time_data_count = 0
    for line in tflines:
        if 'TIME_DATA' in line:
            time_data_count += 1
    if time_data_count > 7:
        return "time_data complete"
    else:
        return "incomplete time_data data"
```

You could also just store the lines in a list instead of reading them twice.

Comment: What does that seek(0) function do? move the pointer back to the beginning of the file? Would it be negated by me closing the file then reopening it? @heitor

Comment: @edo101  Yes, `seek(0)` moves the pointer back to position 0 (the beginning of the file), sorry I didn't make it clear. There should be no problem closing `tfile` and then reopening it.